# How to pass context information to a custom operator<< for std::iostream

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a heavily used (and optimized) type which stores references to more data by using small integers. For debugging I would like to write an `operator<<` which access the additional data for creating a better debug output. How could I pass this additional context information to `operator<<`?

Here is an example:

```
/** Rich information */
struct Item {
  short id;
  std::string name;
  ...
};    
struct Database {
  std::map<short,Item> items;
  ...
};

/** Very optimized light-weight data type */
struct Foo {
  short a, b; // actually references to Item
};

/** for debugging etc. */
void print(std::ostream& os, const Foo& f, const Database& db) {
  os << "(" << db.items[f.a].name << "," << db.items[f.b].name << ")";
}

Database db;
items[0] = {0, "item0"};
items[1] = {1, "item1"};
Foo foo{0,1};

std::cout << "foo="; print(std::cout, foo, db); std::cout << std::endl; // ugly
std::cout << "foo=" << foo << std::endl; // How to get db ???
```

Comment: Isn't `Item` in `std::map<short, Item>` supposed to be `ItemData`?

Comment: Look up the relevant `Item` by `short` from the `Database`? I don't really see why this is about streams.

Comment: How come `print` is returning `os` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own manipulator `print_database` which overloads `operator <<`:

```
class print_database
{
public:
    print_database(const Foo& foo, const Database& db)
        : foo(foo), db(db)
    { }

    template<class cT>
    friend std::basic_ostream<cT>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<cT>& os,
                                              const print_database& manip)
    {
        manip.print(os);
        return os;
    }
private:
    Foo foo;
    Database db;

    template<class cT>
    void print(std::basic_ostream<cT>& os) const
    {
        os << "(" << db.items[foo.a].name << "," << db.items[foo.b].name << ")";
    }
};
```

Then your `print` function can be implemented as:

```
print_database print(const Foo& foo, const Database& db)
{
    return print_database(foo, db);
}
```

So now you can call it as:

```
std::cout << print(foo, db) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use `std::basic_ostream<cT>` instead of `std::ostream`?

Comment: @Danvil We use a templatized version because the user may be printing with a different stream type. If you're only going to be using a narrow character stream, then you can just use `std::ostream`.

Comment: @Danvil Did this answer help? If so, do you mind clicking the checkmark to accept my answer? It helps a lot :)

Comment: Right, of course. Actually I am now using a mixture of your answer and the other one (no need for `print`). But yours was more explicit on how to implement the printer object.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you consider it more or less ugly, but perhaps something like:

```
debug_printer dp { db };
std::cout << dp(foo) << std::endl;
```

Where the `op<<` is overload for debug printer; or `op()` could return a `std::string`.

Comment: And what would `dp(foo)` do?

Comment: @Danvil either return a `std::string`, return a proxy which actually does the printing(meaning that would actually be a generator of some kind), or set some internal state in the printer to "print with food".